# How do you use extensions defined in a nuget package?

Tags: c#, nuget, extension-methods, using, dnx50

I also seem to not be able to figure out what `using` statement to use at the top of my file.

The nuget package is here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/csharp-extensions
The method I'm trying to use from it is Object#Send

so, I call

`<#objectInstanec>.Send("SomeMethod")`

but the compiler says that the method is not defined on type object.
`Send` is defined here though: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/csharp-extensions/blob/master/Extensions/Methods.cs#L26

I've tried various using statements:

```
using csharp_extensions.Extensions.Methods;
using csharp_extensions.Extensions;
using csharp_extensions
```

none seem to work (`csharp_extensions` doesn't exist)

### UPDATE - how I install the package

my project.json:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "System.Reflection": "4.1.0-beta-*",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions": "(1.0.0-rc1-final,]",
        "xunit": "2.1.0-*",
        "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-*",
        "csharp-extensions": "1.0.1"
    },
    "commands": {
        "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "dnxcore50": {
            "_": "this is the recommended windows runtime",
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-*",
                "System.Reflection": "4.1.0-beta-*",
                "System.Reflection.TypeExtensions": "4.1.0-beta-*",
                "System.Runtime.Extensions": "(4.0,]",
                "System.IO": "(4.0,]",
                "csharp-extensions": "1.0.1"

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then I install the dependencies via

`dnu restore`

Comment: Installing the package does not work from Nuget.

Comment: What version of .Net are you targeting?  It looks like this package targets only dnx.

Comment: Oh, right - sorry. I've added how I install my packages to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your NuGet package does not look correct to me. Your assemblies are in **bin\Debug\dnxcore50**. I would take a look at the [NuGet documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/Create/Creating-and-Publishing-a-Package) or download an existing NuGet package that works.

NuGet v2 style packages contain the assemblies inside lib directories. The directory inside the lib directory is named after the target framework. Taking a look at the Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions NuGet package you have an assembly inside both the directories:

```
lib\net451
lib\dotnet5.4
```

So with your NuGet package I believe the assemblies are not being referenced since they are not in the correct directory. The dotnet5.4 directory has the assembly that can be used with the dnxcore target framework.

Also, the project.json should look like this (without system.reflection, as it's redundant)

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions": "(1.0.0-rc1-final,]",
        "System.Reflection": "4.1.0-beta-*",
        "xunit": "2.1.0-*",
        "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-*"
    },
    "commands": {
        "run": "csharp_extensions",
        "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "dnxcore50": {
            "_": "this is the recommended windows runtime",
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-*",
                "System.Reflection.TypeExtensions": "4.1.0-beta-*",
                "System.Runtime.Extensions": "(4.0,]",
                "System.Dynamic.Runtime": "(4.0.0,]",
                "Microsoft.CSharp": "(4.0.0,]",
                "System.IO": "(4.0,]"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to modify the package.json to build to those directories?

Comment: I think you can just run `dnu pack` in the directory where your project.json is. At least that works for me with a ASP.NET 5 Class Library project. That creates a .nupkg with a lib directory. The directories inside have different names (lib\dnxcore50 and lib\dnx451) but I believe NuGet will recognise these.

Comment: after I try the `NuGet Push <path>`, I get this error now: `'csharp-extensions' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Reflection'` what does that mean?

Comment: looks like in addition to dnu pack, I had to also remove some dependencies from my project.json.